# User: batch.amazonaws.com is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, assume-role

I've been trying to create some infrastructure that includes bunch of services like EC2, ECS, S3 and Batch (few more). Everything seems to be fine, till it reaches the step to build the batch process.

I was following a medium blog and here's the CF template: [Github Repo Link](https://github.com/JustinPlute/aws-batch-s3-processor/blob/master/cloudformation/batch.yaml)

This YAML is outdated and I have made some modifications here and there, but not the ones with roles.

I've had more than 3 CloudFormation stacks stuck in roll back because it can't stabilise the Compute Environment it builds from the YAML config I have. I reached out to Compute Environment to see the exact error and this is what I get:

```
DELETING - CLIENT_ERROR - User: batch.amazonaws.com is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::402726478692:role/service-role/AWSBatchServiceRole (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: f9d6c19d-4e77-4814-ac2c-b437e0546977; Proxy: null)
```

Now, It won't even delete this compute environment on automated rollback. But, my main concern is why is it not able to create? I've gone through documentation and few questions here regarding the same topic, but nothing seemed to work.

Here's the excerpt from my YAML config. This part is for compute environment:

```
ComputeEnvironment:
    Type: "AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment"
    Properties:
      Type: MANAGED
      ServiceRole: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/AWSBatchServiceRole"
      ComputeEnvironmentName: !Sub "${Environment}-batch-processing_3"
      ComputeResources:
        MaxvCpus: 1
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecurityGroup
        Type: EC2
        Subnets: !Ref Subnets
        MinvCpus: 1
        InstanceRole: !Ref ECSInstanceProfile
        InstanceTypes:
          - "c6gd.medium"
        Tags: {"Name": !Sub "${Environment} - Batch Instance" }
        DesiredvCpus: 1
      State: ENABLED

  JobQueue:
    DependsOn: ComputeEnvironment
    Type: "AWS::Batch::JobQueue"
    Properties:
      ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
        - Order: 1
          ComputeEnvironment: !Ref ComputeEnvironment
      State: ENABLED
      Priority: 1
      JobQueueName: "HighPriority"

  Job:
    Type: "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition"
    Properties:
      Type: container
      JobDefinitionName: !Sub "${Environment}-batch-s3-processor"
      ContainerProperties:
        Memory: 2048
        Privileged: false
        JobRoleArn: !Ref JobRole
        ReadonlyRootFilesystem: true
        Vcpus: 1
        Image: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${DockerImage}"
      RetryStrategy:
        Attempts: 1

  JobRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      RoleName: !Sub "${Environment}-BatchJobRole"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: 
                - "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                - "batch.amazonaws.com"
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: !Sub "${Environment}-s3-access"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - "s3:*"
                  - "iam:*"
                  - "batch:*"
                Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::batch-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}/*"

  ECSInstanceProfile:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - !Ref ECSRole

  ECSRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      RoleName: !Sub "${Environment}-batch-ecs-role"
      SourceAccount:
        Ref: AWS::AccountId
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: 
                - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                - "batch.amazonaws.com"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub "${Environment}-full-access-for-batch-resource"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - "s3:*"
                  - "iam:*"
                  - "batch:*"
                Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::batch-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}/*"
        - PolicyName: !Sub ${Environment}-ecs-batch-policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "ecs:CreateCluster"
                  - "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance"
                  - "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint"
                  - "ecs:Poll"
                  - "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance"
                  - "ecs:StartTelemetrySession"
                  - "ecs:StartTask"
                  - "ecs:Submit*"
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                  - "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  - "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
                  - "ecr:BatchGetImage"
                  - "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
                  - "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
                  - "s3:*"
                  - "batch:*"
                Resource: "*"
        - PolicyName: !Sub "${Environment}-ecs-instance-policy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "ecs:DescribeContainerInstances"
                  - "ecs:ListClusters"
                  - "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition"
                  - "s3:*"
                  - "batch:*"
                Resource: "*"
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "ecs:*"
                  - "s3:*"
                  - "batch:*"
                Resource: "*"
```

As you can see I've tried giving more than enough permissions in these policies which is already a bad practice, but I still can't get it to Assume Role. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have checked and I can see the `AWSBatchServiceRole` and I have added `AWSBatchServiceRole` and `AWSBatchFullAccess` permissions to it and in the `Trust Relationship`, I do have `Sts:AssumeRole` in there. This is the JSON from `Trust Relationship`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "batch.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does the `AWSBatchServiceRole` contain the proper assume role policy / trust relationship? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/service_IAM_role.html

Comment: Just checked and yep, I do have that role, but it's the default policy and the default perms that "AWS Managed" policy has.

Comment: And your account id is in fact the one in the error message 402726478692? Or are you trying to do something cross account?

Comment: Yep, it's the same ID and I'm not trying to do anything cross-account or even cross-region. It's all in the same region, under same account. Updated question with more info on what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my friend figured it out and it worked. It was a dumb mistake.

Changed `arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/service-role/AWSBatchServiceRole` to `arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/AWSBatchServiceRole` and it worked.

`service-role/` isn't required, at least not now.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, the answer is not to specify the ServiceRole at all. The resulting compute environments will use the (new) AWS-managed AWSServiceRoleForBatch by default.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).